# Triac gate burns after getting current on it

Tags: triac

I have a T1635H-T triac, that i would like to control with MOC3041. I use typical circuit from the optocoupler datasheet:

[image]
The only difference is that i'm using 330Ohm resistor instead of 360Ohm. As a test load i use 40W incandescent bulb.

For some reason, when i enable the optocoupler by closing led-side circuit, triac burns almost immediately with clearly visible clearly visible traces of damage on the gate pin.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen ...

Comment: If the main triac is burning out it sounds as though you are short-circuiting the mains. Are you sure that your load is connected? Again, add a photo of your setup.

Comment: Thre [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/19/30/72/5b/0d/f2/4b/97/CD00133090.pdf/files/CD00133090.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00133090.pdf) says that I_GT(MAX) is just 35 mA. I suspect that you're dumping way too much current into the gate.

Comment: If you have let the magic smoke out then it probably won't work any more...

Comment: @DaveTweed probably yo are right. I expected MOC3041 to limit current here :) But now i checked optocoupler datasheet and clearly see, that tat was my misunderstanding. What is the best way to limit current on a gate then? Straightforward approach with current limiting resistor will give me a couple of watts and that's a lot

Comment: The datasheet also says that I_GT(MIN) is guaranteed to be no more than 5% of the max value, or 1.75 mA. If you pick, say, 2.4 mA (RMS)  to be safe, then you need a gate series resistor (the one connected to pin 6 of the coupler) of 100k and 1W to limit the current at 240 V.

Comment: @DaveTweed i replaced pin 6 resistor with 1w 100k resistor and when i turned mains, triac died slowly. My load (incandescent bulb) turned on for about 0.5-1 second, even though optocoupler was off. Triac died after that with smell of magic smoke.

Answer (score 1):

What you say is pretty surprising as this triac is pretty much overkill for a simple 40W resistive load.

The figure in the [MOC3041](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MO/MOC3041M.pdf) datasheet shows a very standard circuit for controlling a triac in particular,using a 300 ohm resistor instead of 360 Ohm is perfectly okay for a 240V AC main.

The most likely cause of the death of your triac is that the capacitor discharges too fast in the triac when the latter is turned ON. Using a higher capacitor value than 0.01µF could induce a high current spike that can kill the triac.

My recommendations:

1. Please check that you used the right scheme: are you using a
   110V AC main or a 240V AC main?
2. Please check the rating of your capacitor ; it must be less than or equal to 0.01µF.
3. If all you want to control is a resistive load, you can also completely
   remove the snubber. The snubber is only useful in case of noisy environment or highly inductive loads; on top of that the [T1635H](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/t1635h.pdf) seem to have pretty solid snubberless performances that could probably allow you to [remove the snubber](http://studylib.net/doc/18191557/new-triacs--is-the-snubber-circuit-necessary%3F) all together.

Comment: I use 40W load only for prototyping. Actual load will be 2kW heating element, but it is easier to debug with 40w bulb.  Snubber was the first thing i suspected and removed it at my first try with no effect. Mains are 240VAC, definitely. @DaveTweed pointed to possible gate over current, so i replaced pin 6 resistor with 100k 1w resistor, but without any success.

Comment: * 100k is too low I thik. You'd better keep it at 300/1W.
* Gate over current is unlikely at 40W, as it represents only 0.2A in the whole system, way under the 1A maximum current in allowed for the gate.
* Are you sure that you keep the IGT ABOVE 35mA?

Comment: One more question: have you re-measured your 300 Ohm resistor after the failure?